# Anonymous class hidden cause leaks

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I read a lot that `final context` inside anonymous class can cause a memory leak.
But on my implementation, when item is clicked, the using of `MyActivity.this` inside the anonymous implementation can cause a mem leak of the context?
Is it the same like the popular memory leak cause (final context)?
loader function is async and take X seconds to finish.

```
public class MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //.....
        //.....
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(persons, new MyAdapter.ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void ItemListener(final Person person) {
                if (person != null) {
                    loader(MyActivity.this, person);
                }
            }
        });
        
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as the item listener instance exists it will reference your activity which might still reference your context, so yes, this could be a memory leak. If it **is** can't be said for sure without looking at your whole codebase.

Comment: What you looking for? the adapter?